# Expandable List using Python Tkinter

Tags: python, list, listbox, tkinter, expandable

I know how to create a Listbox using Tkinter but this only allows me to display a list of single items. I need to create a expandable list that allows the user to hit something along the lines of a + next to the item which in turn opens up a new list with + buttons next to each item until you reach the leaf of a list. I was wondering if there was a way to implement this type of expandable list using Tkinter or if not if there was a different Python GUI tool that could do so?

Comment: Like a [QTreeView](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=qtreeview&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1280&bih=937) in PyQt4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widget you are looking for is commonly called a "tree" or "hierarchical tree".

If you're using python2.7 or greater you can use [ttk.Treeview](http://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) widget.

For older versions of python you can use [Tix.Tree](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tix.Tree-class.html). You can also search for "tkinter tree" on google and you'll find several other variations such as [this one](http://home.gna.org/oomadness/en/editobj/tree_widget/index.html).